# Python 3 else for all previous ifs

Tags: python, if-statement

Say I have the following Python 3 code:

```
def foo(number_a, number_b):
    if number_a >= 0:
        print("a is Positive")
    if number_b <= 100:
        print("b is <= 100")
    else:
        print("a is negative and b > 100")
```

How can I have the `else` fire if and only if both conditions are false?

I could do something like this:

```
doElse = True
if condition1:
    doElse = False
    # do something
if condition2:
    doElse = False
    # do something
# condition3...conditionN
if doElse:
    # do the else
```

But that would require setting the variable, then changing it for every `if`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you just change the second if to elif, it does what you describe. No repetition.

Comment: No, there's no way to do this - each `if` starts a completely new control flow.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon My example was bad because "banana" != "apple"... See the new one.

Comment: The edit totally destroys the meaning of the question (plus, you still got a few apples in there).

Comment: @phihag How so? It now shows what I'm actually asking: How to apply the  `else` to multiple `if`s that _may be simutaniously true_

Comment: No number is both less than 0 and greater than 100.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon Crap. Gotta get an example that actually makes sense. The idea still stands, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your first and second condition are mutally exclusive, you should always solve this with a single if/elif/else construct. Using your original example:

```
if word == "banana":
    print("word is banana")
elif word == "apple":
    print("word is not banana, but it is apple")
else:
    print("word is neither banana, nor apple, but something else")
```

If you have conditions which are not mutally exclusive, then this obviously doesn’t work as you want to continue checking the other conditions as well.

In that case, you should try to find a common condition for all of them. This can be as simple as combining the conditions with or:

```
if number >= 0 or number <= 100:
    if number >= 0:
        print("Positive")
    if number <= 100:
        print("<= 100")
else:
    print("x < 0 or x > 100")
```

But you could also combine them if that’s possible:

```
if 0 <= number <= 100:
    …
```

Or you could replace the `else` by an inverted condition:

```
if number >= 0:
    print("Positive")
if number <= 100:
    print("<= 100")

if number < 0 or number > 100:
    print("x < 0 or x > 100")
```

For everything more complicated than that, you will have to keep track of this in another way, involving more code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reorder the if statements like so:

```
def foo(number_a, number_b):
    if number_a < 0 and number_b > 100:
        print("a is negative and b > 100")
    elif number_a >= 0:
        print("a is Positive")
    else:
        print("b is <= 100")
```

Comment: Sorry, my example was bad, please see it again.

Comment: Are you working with a range of number between 0 and 100, or is it possible to get numbers outside of that range?